# className, SetAttribute ou classList.add

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Eu possuo uma lista JSON que cria diversos objetos de um blog e me deparei com as seguintes formas de adicionar classes aos objetos HTML que crio após carregar a lista: className, setAttribute e classList.add.

Obviamente eu estou dando preferência pelo classList.add ou até o className, mas descobri que o setAttribute possui uma performance comparavel ou até melhor que eles. Como essa definição da classe CSS ficaria dentro de o set privado, alguém tem alguma recomendação?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Após fazer pesquisar no site da MDN, W3chools e rodar testes no meu navegador e no measurethat, descobri algumas coisas interessantes sobre os 3 metodos. Como eles variam em velocidade e funcionalidade, montei um post para poder explicar como cheguei na minha respota.. segue abaixo um resumo dela

**A performance**

Resolvi pesquisar para saber qual seria a melhor opção. Segundo o site https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/54/0/classname-vs-setattribute-vs-classlist, alguém já havia se perguntado o mesmo. Eles fizeram o seguinte teste que rodei no Chrome, Edge e Firefox:

1º lugar: className

2º lugar: setAttribute (exceto Edge)

3º lugar: classList

*Resultado em operações por segundo

**Na prática**

Mesmo sendo bem claro, o teste acima não é um absoluto, devemos levar em consideração outros fatores como manipulação, funcionalidades e boas práticas.

1. className: Permite a manipulação das classes no formato string, nesse caso tendo uma string com todas as classes escritas dentro e permitindo a manipulação dos dados neste formato. Por ser uma funcionalidade antiga, é utilizado por diversos navegadores
2. setAttribute: O set atribute simplesmente faz isso, define o valor dentro de um atributo. Existe o getAttribute que permite visualizar este valor, mas a manipulação é limitada a isso.
3. classList: Coloca as classes dentro de uma lista para serem manipuladas de forma ordenada através de diversos métodos específicos. A nível de funcionalidade é a mais prática, mas além de ter uma performance inferior, não foi implementada em navegadores mais antigos.

**Conclusão**

Acredito que o className e o classList sejam os melhores candidatos. Se você precisa de performance e está apenas definindo e apagando classes, utilize o className. Agora se você tem um sistema que precisa procurar por classes dentro da tag ou adicionar apenas se não existe, poupe o esforço de criar uma lógica para isso e utilize o classList.

Para a versão completa desta resposta, veja o post: http://www.mundojs.com.br/blog/b00020.html

Comment: Considere que você fazer uma pergunta e a responder com link para um site particular ou artigo próprio pode ser considerado uma forma de SPAM. Não há problema algum em você perguntar e responder. Se for fazer referências externas, coloque fontes oficiais.

Comment: Eu não chamaria exatamente de spam como estão dizendo, mas é mais legal se puder reproduzir o artigo aqui além de dar o link.

Comment: Eu queria colocar tudo aqui, mas é um post com mais de 400 palavras, 3 imagens de testes de performance e o código fonte do teste... vou alterar a resposta para incluir o maximo possivel, mas acho que não vai ficar tão legal.....

Comment: O campo de resposta suporta até 30000 caracteres, então acho que comporta, sim :D

Comment: Essa parte foi tranquilo... era mais pelo conteudo visual..
Mas ja coloquei uma nova resposta com fazendo os ajustes necessários, espero que agrade mais o pessoal :)

Comment: O conteúdo visual acho que você não consegue incluir por ter poucos pontos no site, certo? Podemos incluir pra você se achar importante. Não tem problema ter conteúdo visual nas respostas, pelo contrário (se ele for relevante, claro).

Answer (score 1):

O `setAttribute` jamais deveria ser utilizado para **adicionar** uma classe a um elemento, pelo simples fato que o novo valor irá sobrescrever o atual e você não tem controle sobre quais classes o elemento tem neste momento. Se em uma parte você adiciona a classe `x` e em outro a classe `y`, você vai ter muita inconsistência no seu layout. Para contornar esse problema, você teria que ler o valor atual e concatenar a nova classe a ele, mas é justamente isso que o `className` faz.

Já, entre escolher `className` e `classList`, a própria documentação da MDN, por exemplo responde isso:

> Usar [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) é uma alternativa conveniente para acessar a lista de classes de um elemento como uma sequência delimitada por espaço através de [`element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/className).

O único detalhe é que o `classList` pode não estar implementado em todos os navegadores que você pretende oferecer suporte, então consulte a tabela de compatibilidade antes de utilizá-lo em produção.

Comment: Olá Anderson, cheguei na mesma conclusão sobre o setattribute pois ele realmente não auxilia, talvez no caso de ser apenas 1 unica classe e não mexer mais. do resto eu concordo com você, entrei no MDN e site de teste de performance e acabei escolhendo o classList pelo maleabilidade. Obrigado